# Color highlight function calls in VIM

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know a way to color highlight function calls in Vim?

I know that some plugins could do something like that by keeping record of tags, but with what I've found online, I could not figure out how to make it work.

I've tried using [easy tags](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) (which, by the way, doesn't seem to be maintained anymore) and [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags), but to be quite honest, I haven't come much close to make any of them to work.

On the other hand, I imagine that it would be quite simple to implement a script to highlight anything that lies between a dot and a left parentheses or a blank space and a left parentheses (as in `.anyCodeAtAll()`, `anotherCode()`), but I have no idea how to do it. It would be a incomplete solution of course, but it would be good enough for my purposes at the moment.

Does anyone know how to make that work?

Comment: Have you looked at the [installation instructions for easy tags](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags/blob/master/INSTALL.md)? What plug-in manager are you using, if any?

Comment: I'm using Plug. Easy tags was successfully installed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: see my answer, wanted to put here but formatting problems

Comment: Might be a little late here but for easy tags to work properly you need to build your tags in a certain way. In particular you need to supply the following to ctags ctags --fields=+l --c-kinds=+p --c++-kinds=+p. It is not mentioned in the README but deep in the bowels of this manual https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags/blob/master/doc/easytags.txt#L479. After doing this, it highlights everything covered by your tags file.

Answer (score 1):

I have something like that in my configuration, but it's quite language specific. For example for Golang, I have a `~/.vim/after/go.vim` which contains:

```
syntax match goCustomParen     "(" contains=cParen
syntax match goCustomFuncDef   "func\s\+\w\+\s*(" contains=goDeclaration,goCustomParen
" Exclude import as function name, for multi-line imports
syntax match goCustomFunc      "import\s\+(\|\(\w\+\s*\)(" contains=goCustomParen,goImport
syntax match goCustomScope     "\."
syntax match goCustomAttribute "\.\w\+" contains=goCustomScope
syntax match goCustomMethod    "\.\w\+\s*(" contains=goCustomScope,goCustomParen

highlight def link goCustomMethod Function
highlight def link goCustomAttribute Identifier

highlight goCustomFuncDef ctermfg=13
highlight goCustomFunc ctermfg=43
highlight goCustomAttribute ctermfg=247
highlight goCustomMethod ctermfg=33
```

And for Python, I have a `~/.vim/after/python.vim`:

```
syntax match pyCustomParen     "(" contains=cParen
syntax match pyCustomFunc      "\w\+\s*(" contains=pyCustomParen
syntax match pyCustomScope     "\."
syntax match pyCustomAttribute "\.\w\+" contains=pyCustomScope
syntax match pyCustomMethod    "\.\w\+\s*(" contains=pyCustomScope,pyCustomParen

highlight def link pyCustomFunc  Function
highlight def link pyCustomMethod Function
highlight def link pyCustomAttribute Identifier

highlight pyCustomFunc ctermfg=43
highlight pyCustomAttribute ctermfg=247
highlight pyCustomMethod ctermfg=33
```

In each case, the first block defines what is a function, a method, an attribute, and so on, the second block link these custom definition to the generic classes "Function, Identifier..." and the 3rd block defines the colors.

The files need to be in the `after` directory to be executed after the colorscheme and highlights definitions.

Here's a side by side comparison of with and without these settings (look on the last 3 lines):

[image]

Unless someone has a better solution, you could adapt the above for the language you need it.

Comment: Wow. That's great! Thanks for the help :D

Comment: If the answer helped you, don't forget to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have not installed your plug-in correctly.
Try following these steps (or retrace your steps) and see if it works / missed any steps out:

`cd ~` Go to home directory.
`vim .vimrc` open .vimrc
Insert:

```
call plug#begin()  
Plug 'xolox/vim-easytags'  
call plug#end()
```

[easytags#Options](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags#options) states easytags should work out of the box, but you could add option here in the
`.vimrc` file now or later,
e.g. put:
`let g:easytags_syntax_keyword = 'always'`
afer the call plug block.
Anyway.
`:wq` write quit the .vimrc

`source ~/.vimrc` unsure if required as will do later
`vim test.js` open vim with test.whatever language you know.
`:PlugInstall` in vim
Here might take a bit of time.
Then `:q` out of that window.
`:source ~/.vimrc` this is needed

Then test out to see if you have syntax highlighting.
I'm pretty sure this is along the right lines. Might be misspelled plugin name.